# How to create ranges inside a Select in a sql clause

Tags: sql, pyspark, group-by

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-------+------+------+----------+
|cd_cli   |vl_ren |max_t0|max_12|dt_mvtc   |
+---------+-------+------+------+----------+
|514208   |1040.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|30230361 |3720.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|201188220|2742.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|204080612|2968.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|209727665|860.00 |0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|212491854|792.00 |0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|300597652|1663.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|300836378|2366.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|301040450|3394.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
|302394154|2218.00|0     |0     |2017-01-31|
+---------+-------+------+------+----------+
```

And I want to select:

```
vlren = spark.sql('''select dt_mvtc,
                        vl_ren,
                        max_t0,
                        max_12,
                        count(cd_cli) as count_cd_cli
                 from table_xx
                 group by dt_mvtc,vl_ren,max_t0,max_12
                 order by dt_mvtc''')
```

But the `group by` is not quite well because the values for `vl_ren` are sometimes very close to one another - they can differ by 0.01 - thus I am trying to group them by ranges, but I am not sure how to put the ranges inside the select clause:

```
    %%time
%%spark

vlren = spark.sql('''select dt_mvtc,
                            vl_ren,
                            max_t0,
                            max_12,
                            count(cd_cli) as count_cd_cli
                          CASE
                              WHEN vl_ren >= 0 AND vl_ren < 1000 THEN 0
                              WHEN vl_ren >= 1000 AND vl_ren < 2000 THEN 1
                              WHEN vl_ren >= 2000 AND vl_ren < 3000 THEN 2
                              WHEN vl_ren >= 3000 THEN 3
                           END AS values
                        FROM
                          vl_ren
                        ) AS vl_ren_range
                     GROUP BY dt_mvtc,vl_ren_range.values,max_12
                     from sbx_d4n0cbf.renda_presumida 
                     order by dt_mvtc''')
```

The expected output is to have
is this right? are there any other better aproach?

Comment: Can provide an example with `vl_ren` in close ranges and describe the expected output taking into account your range logic.

Comment: I edited. `vl_ren` has values like 1300.01 and 1300.55, and I want them grouped inside a range [1300, 1400]. I will plot this values and I want to plot a count of the values inside these ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL GROUP BY can't use column aliases from a SELECT at the same level, as conceptually GROUP BY happens *before* SELECT.

So you project the new grouping column in a subquery, CTE or a separate dataframe.
eg

```
  select dt_mvtc,values,max_12, count(cd_cli) count_cd_cli
  from (
         select dt_mvtc,
                max_t0,
                max_12,
                cd_cli,
                CASE
                  WHEN vl_ren >= 0 AND vl_ren < 1000 THEN 0
                  WHEN vl_ren >= 1000 AND vl_ren < 2000 THEN 1
                  WHEN vl_ren >= 2000 AND vl_ren < 3000 THEN 2
                  WHEN vl_ren >= 3000 THEN 3
                END AS values
        from sbx_d4n0cbf.renda_presumida 
) AS vl_ren_range
GROUP BY dt_mvtc,values,max_12
order by dt_mvtc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`round`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.round) down the `vl_ren` values to the 100th floor of the `vl_ren` value, and then group based on this. This way you don't have to create `case` statements depending on data distribution.

```py
data = [(514208, 1040.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(30230361, 3720.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(201188220, 2742.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(204080612, 2968.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(209727665, 860.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(212491854, 792.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(300597652, 1663.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(300597652, 1643.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),        
(300836378, 2366.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(301040450, 3394.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),
(302394154, 2218.00, 0, 0, "2017-01-31"),]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("cd_cli", "vl_ren" ,"max_t0", "max_12", "dt_mvtc"))

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

spark.sql('''select dt_mvtc,
                            max_t0,
                            max_12,
                            CASE 
                                WHEN (vl_ren - round(vl_ren, -2)) <= 0 THEN round(vl_ren, -2) - 100
                                ELSE round(vl_ren, -2)
                            END AS vl_ren,
                            count(cd_cli) as count_cd_cli
                        FROM
                          df_table
                        GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
                        ''').show()
```

### Output

```
+----------+------+------+------+------------+
|   dt_mvtc|max_t0|max_12|vl_ren|count_cd_cli|
+----------+------+------+------+------------+
|2017-01-31|     0|     0| 800.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|1000.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0| 700.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|2300.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|1600.0|           2|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|2700.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|3300.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|2900.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|2200.0|           1|
|2017-01-31|     0|     0|3700.0|           1|
+----------+------+------+------+------------+
```